# To search transaction using custom attribute in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

Hey is there **any way to look up transaction details** by my `Custom` attribute which i passed during `SetExpressCheckout` call to API.

Paypal is providing transaction search by

- TransactionSearch API - Which needs `Startdate` as param.
- GetTransactionDetails API - Which needs unique `Transaction ID`  as param. ( which is only available only if `DoExpressCheckout` is successful ).

Both of these do not fit my solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the "PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM" parameter in [SetExpressCheckout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) call which you can set to your customized value and later can use in the [Transaction search API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) call.

Comment: I will second that this is the best method to use, however, you need to make sure you include the INVNUM parameter in DoExpressCheckoutPayment, not just SetExpressCheckout.  If it's not included in DECP then it will not be included in the final transaction details at PayPal and will not be available to search on.

Comment: One more thing, Do i need to still send @STARTDATE as a param when making Transaction Search API Call ??
Or i can just mention this INVNUM to the transaction search API Call.

Comment: Yes you need to send the start date as well because its a mandatory parameter as per the documentation .https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/